# Will global Warming continue to produce winter storms in the Northeast US?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

Will GW just cause more winter storms in Northeast US or will all of US have colder winters ? This winter in East TX we had three record cold snaps and I lost a lot of Camellia Japonica buds and blooms. Most years I lose a few blooms but usually not the buds also. This is the most I have lost in 20 years. I am hoping we will not get the cold like the northeast.. I have watched the weather channels ; they usually explain how GW causes more storms/ rain, etc, but they have not yet explained the relationship to GW for these storms.

Comment: More winter storms and colder winters don't go hand in hand.   It wasn't a cold winter in the Northeast overall, despite a few cold snaps and an unusually high number of March blizzards.   February set some heat records in the NE.   https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/wide_full_width_image_no_crop/public/sites/default/files/february-2018-us-average-temperature-percentiles-map.png?itok=fe5OG7aP     I like your question, but you should remove the "colder winters" part of it as that has little to do with winter storms.

Comment: Since the question regarded winter, not February, [this](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/monitoring-content/sotc/national/grid-ranks-temp/grid-ranks-tavg-201712-201802.gif) would be a better image.  From station climate reports (see [kamala.cod.edu](http://kamala.cod.edu) or [NWS](http://sercc.com/nowdata.html)) March appears to be 1-3 degrees below average so far for much of the mid-Atlantic up to New York, but 2-4 degrees above average for more northern\eastern parts of New England.  And basically all of Texas is 2-3 degrees above normal this month.